# Second for loop not being executed

Tags: java

I have this simple program where I am trying to output all the cards in a deck of cards.
However it is only outputting the 1-9 cards of each set, and none of the face cards. i.e. only the for loop with `j` is being executed, but not the `f` `for` loop involving the `cardFace` array. Why is this?

```
public class cards {

    public final String cardValue[] = {"Heart", "Diamond", "Spade", "Club"};
    public final String cardFace[] = {"Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};

    public void outputCards() {

        for (int i = 0; i < cardValue.length; i++) {
            int k = 1;

            if (k <= 9) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
                    System.out.println("The Card is a " + j + " And is a " + cardValue[i]);
                    k++;
                }
            } else {
                for (int f = 10; f < cardFace.length; f++) {
                    System.out.println("The Card is a " + f + " And is a " + cardValue[i]);
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your code got to the loop it will never run because this for condition will never be true:

```
for(int f = 10; f < cardFace.length; f++){
```

If you inspect the cardFace array and get its length, you'll see that it is always less than f.

Most all of your logic is a bit off. I suggest that you write out the program steps on paper first, thinking through the steps before trying to commit it to code, because usually these types mistakes are caused by coding before thinking.

Comment: ok thankyou for you help, this is my first program in java so i will use your advice. The program works now anyway as i removed the if statement and set f as 0 in the for loop

Answer (score 4):

```
 for(int i = 0; i <cardValue.length; i++){
        int k = 1;
        if(k <=9){
        ...
```

Given the preceding code, it'll always enter on the if and never on the else. Therefore, the for that uses the f variable, will never be executed.